# How to convert case class to JSON in Play framework 2.3.x (Scala)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Anyone can show me how to convert case class class instances to JSON in Play framework (particularly Play v2.3.x) with Scala?

For example I have code like this:

```
case class Foo(name: String, address: String)

def index = Action {
      request => {
        val foo = Foo("John Derp", "Jem Street 21")  // I want to convert this object to JSON
        Ok(Json.toJson(foo))    // I got error at here
      }
}
```

The error message:

> Cannot write an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.data bind.JsonNode
>   to HTTP response. Try to define a
>   Writeable[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]

**UPDATE:** I found out the above error is caused by wrong import of the `Json` class, it should be: `import play.api.libs.json.Json`. However I still got error on implicit problem below.

I have read [this tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonHttp), but when I tried the implicit `Writes[Foo]` code:

```
  implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = (
        (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
            (JsPath \ "address").write[String]
        )(unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

I got `Can't resolve symbol and` and `Can't resolve symbol unlift` error in Intellij. Also the tutorial's code looks complex just for the conversion of an object to JSON. I wonder if there is more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get an `Writes[Foo]` instance by using `Json.writes`:

```
implicit val fooWrites = Json.writes[Foo]
```

Having this implicit in scope is all you need to convert `Foo` to JSON. See the documetnation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception)  and [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) for more info about JSON reads/writes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Do you know where can I find simple guide or documentation about using Json in Play 2.3? Also, can you explain the error `Can't resolve symbol and` (and `unlift` as well) in the original implicit Writes I've tried? (see the updated question, I have put the code there)

Comment: To resolve the symbol error you need to import `play.api.libs.functional.syntax._`. The documentation links I've provided should answer your question about `unlift` as well contain enough general information about Play JSON .

Comment: Hi, once again, thanks a lot for the help. I wonder why Intellij can't detect the import.

Answer (score 1):

The second problem - `Can't resolve symbol and` - is an [Intellij bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8241) introduced in version 1.3 of the Scala plugin.  In version 1.3.3 of the Scala plugin, there's now a workaround - set preference checkbox:

> Languages & Frameworks > Scala > Core (default) tab > Use old
>   implicit search algorithm